# Nested boolean aggregation in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have json payloads as such

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 61,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "CAojVWwBO8H0jj7a_j3P",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "appName" : "BigApp",
          "appVer" : "1.0",
          "reviews" : {
            "reviewer" : {
              "value" : "Bob"
            },
            "testsPass" : [
              {
                "name" : "unit",
                "pass" : false
              },
              {
                "name" : "integraton",
                "pass" : false
              },
              {
                "name" : "ui",
                "pass" : false
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In elastic I want to aggregate the boolean values under `testsPass` to return *true* if all of the `pass` values are *true*.

I am new to Elastic and struggling to write a query in that shape, can someone please help?

So far I have tried [nested aggregators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) but can't get the syntax right.

Comment: is this what you want to do?  `testPass` array should contain `pass` as `true` for all the objects to return `true` otherwise return `false`?

Comment: @JBone correct, it’s a logical and for all items in that array

Comment: Ok in that case, why don't you query for `pass:false` and based on the query result, if the documents count is more than one, then yes there are `pass = fail` documents and if not then all the documents have `pass=true`? does this logic work? if so I can write the query

Comment: @JBone that’s not quite what I am after. E.g. I have 10 documents, each document has an array of those. It should only return that document if *all* items in that particular document have _pass:true_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your data, I'm assuming the structure of your mapping is as follow:

### Mapping:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "appName":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "appVer": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "reviews":{
        "properties": {
          "reviewer":{
            "properties":{
              "value": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "testsPass":{
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST myindex/_doc/1
{  
   "appName":"BigApp",
   "appVer":"1.0",
   "reviews":{  
      "reviewer":{  
         "value":"Bob"
      },
      "testsPass":[  
         {  
            "name":"unit",
            "pass":false
         },
         {  
            "name":"integraton",
            "pass":false
         },
         {  
            "name":"ui",
            "pass":false
         }
      ]
   }
}

POST myindex/_doc/2
{  
   "appName":"MidApp",
   "appVer":"1.0",
   "reviews":{  
      "reviewer":{  
         "value":"Bob"
      },
      "testsPass":[  
         {  
            "name":"unit",
            "pass":true
         },
         {  
            "name":"integraton",
            "pass":true
         },
         {  
            "name":"ui",
            "pass":true
         }
      ]
   }
}

POST myindex/_doc/3
{  
   "appName":"SmallApp",
   "appVer":"1.0",
   "reviews":{  
      "reviewer":{  
         "value":"Bob"
      },
      "testsPass":[  
         {  
            "name":"unit",
            "pass":true
         },
         {  
            "name":"integraton",
            "pass":true
         },
         {  
            "name":"ui",
            "pass":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Note that in the list of the above documents, only the document having `appName: MidApp`(2nd document) has the list of all `true` values.

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST myindex/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "pass_reviewers":{  
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "nested":{  
                        "path":"reviews.testsPass",
                        "query":{  
                           "match":{  
                              "reviews.testsPass.pass":"true"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "must_not":[  
                  {  
                     "nested":{  
                        "path":"reviews.testsPass",
                        "query":{  
                           "match":{  
                              "reviews.testsPass.pass":"false"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "myhits":{  
               "top_hits":{  
                  "size":10
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the above returns only the concerned document as result of [Top Hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html). The main aggregation over here is in filter section which is just a [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "pass_reviewers" : {
      "doc_count" : 1,             <------ Note this. Returns count of docs. This is result of filtered aggregation
      "myhits" : {                 <------ Start of top hits aggregation
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 1,                    
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : 1.0,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "myindex",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "2",                 <----- Document 
              "_score" : 1.0,
              "_source" : {
                "appName" : "MidApp",
                "appVer" : "1.0",
                "reviews" : {
                  "reviewer" : {
                    "value" : "Bob"
                  },
                  "testsPass" : [
                    {
                      "name" : "unit",
                      "pass" : true
                    },
                    {
                      "name" : "integraton",
                      "pass" : true
                    },
                    {
                      "name" : "ui",
                      "pass" : true
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just in case if you just want the query to return the documents having all `true`, and not necessarily make use of aggregation, you can simply make use of the below query:

### Query:

```
POST myindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"reviews.testsPass",
                  "query":{  
                     "match":{  
                        "reviews.testsPass.pass":"true"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"reviews.testsPass",
                  "query":{  
                     "match":{  
                        "reviews.testsPass.pass":"false"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Basically the core execution logic is the same in both the queries, I've just narrowed down the logic you are looking for.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.597837,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.597837,
        "_source" : {
          "appName" : "MidApp",
          "appVer" : "1.0",
          "reviews" : {
            "reviewer" : {
              "value" : "Bob"
            },
            "testsPass" : [
              {
                "name" : "unit",
                "pass" : true
              },
              {
                "name" : "integraton",
                "pass" : true
              },
              {
                "name" : "ui",
                "pass" : true
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that indepth answer but it doesn't work in Kibana7.2, I get the error _[nested] nested object under path [reviews.testsPass] is not of nested type_ and _illegal_state_exception_

Comment: Ahh I see the issue.  Well it would work in ES 7.2. From the above comment, you do not have a `nested` type in your case. There is a difference between `nested` type and `object` type in Elasticsearch. Could you update the mapping of that index in your question? The query works fine as per the mapping I've mentioned in the answer. Just do a `http://host:port/myindex/_mapping?pretty` in your browser and share what you observe.

Comment: Also, it would be useful, if you just execute the above steps I've mentioned and see how that works starting from creating the mapping to running the query. I'd suggest you to spend sometime in understanding nested and object type in ES. It would be important to understand the diff between them as you can model your docs accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, got it :)